# Query all issues for the currently active project in Jira

Tags: jira

I would like to create a general query that is active in the web interface that selects all issues for the currently selected project.

For example if I have two projects

- PROJ1
- PROJ2

to select all issues for PROJ1 I would create a query

```
Project = PROJ1
```

However, if I have a multitude of projects I need to create a query specific to that particular project.

What I would like to do is create a query such as

```
Project = CurrentProject
```

Is there a query syntax that allows me to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the [Create JQL currentProject() function](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23895) issue is still unresolved.

However there exists [CurrentProjectFunction](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.olegburmistrov.jira.CurrentProjectFunction) plugin on MarketPlace which gives you following ability in JQL:

`project = currentProject()`

Answer (score 0):

This must be new because I cannot find anyone mentioning it, this works nicely for me

`project = "{{ project.name }}"`

https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/jira-smart-values-projects/