# Use a filter in JIRA on different project dashboards

Tags: jira

I'm creating different dashboards for different JIRA projects. On every dashboard I'm using the same filters. Ex. 'Open issues', 'Issue planned',... I have to duplicate every filter because there is one filter criteria that is changing for every project (project=...). Is there a way to use a variable in the filter (ex. for project) and to define that variable on the level of the dashboard? 
Ex.
Dashboard for project 1 contains a filter: 'Open issues project 1' with a filter criteria 'project = PROJECT1'.
Dashboard for project 2 contains a filter: 'Open issues project 2' with a filter criteria 'project = PROJECT2'.
I search for a solution where I can define a variable Project that I can set on the dashboard level. Then I can use only one filter 'Open issues' with a filter criteria 'project = %Project'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query all issues for the currently active project in Jira](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899994/query-all-issues-for-the-currently-active-project-in-jira)

Comment: accidental comment ignore